# Spring Boot - Assert Application Load Failure

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am testing a line in my code that is supposed to cause a failure when loading a Spring Boot application context. However, using `@SpringBootTest` will not help in this situation because there will be an (expected) failure in the application initialization, and the test method will never be reached.

```
@SpringBootTest
class SomeTestClass {

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext applicationContext

  @Test
  void someTestCase() {
    //some assert about application context   
  }
}
```

Is there any way to configure a `@SpringBootTest` that will survive a failure on the class level? Alternatively, is there any way to manually run a mini Spring Boot Application of just the affected components?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you should use SpringRunner.

The SpringRunner provides support for loading a Spring ApplicationContext and having beans @Autowired into your test instance. It actually does a whole lot more than that (covered in the Spring Reference Manual), but that's the basic idea.

So you can add it like that :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class SomeTestClass {

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext applicationContext

  @Test
  void someTestCase() {
    //some assert about application context   
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, this does not help because the scenario in question has an anticipated failure, so this will fail before getting to the test moethod. Also, @SpringBootTest already includes the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` or `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` in modern versions of Spring Boot.

Comment: did you found a solution to assert that spring boot fails in dome conditions ?  could you share it please ?